# Using a wildcard in Regex at the end of a URL in GA

Tags: regex, url, google-analytics, wildcard

I'm a newbie at Regex. I'm trying to get a report in GA that returns all pages after a certain point in the URL.

For example: 
http://www.essentialibiza.com/ibiza-club-tickets/carl-cox/14-June-2016/

I want to see all dates so: http://www.essentialibiza.com/ibiza-club-tickets/carl-cox/*

Here's what I've got so far in my regex:

```
^https:\/\/www\.essentialibiza\.com\/ibiza-club-tickets\/carl-cox(?=(?:\/.*)?$)
```

Comment: From what I know, a mere `https?://www\.essentialibiza\.com/ibiza-club-tickets/carl-cox(/|$)` should be enough.

Comment: Thanks - I want a listing of all dates for that event (carl cox) so anything that comes after carl-cox/. https?://www\.essentialibiza\.com/ibiza-club-tickets/carl-cox(/|$) seems to be exactly what I need! Thank you :)

Comment: You might be overthinking this. If you create a custom report via the interface (I assume that is what you are doing) and use a filter you can set the condition to regex and simply enter the start of your page path (if you filter by the page field). GA will just assume that you meant to sue a wildcard and show all subordinate pages in that pagepath (in your example entering "/ibiza-club-tickets/carl-cox" will filter for all pages that contain that particular string).  GA regex is quite forgiving.

Comment: Alternative solution that might be better: don't use regex.  Use the equivalent to the Content Drilldown report - pagePathLevel1=="ibiiza-club-tickets", pagePathLevel2=="carl-cox", and look at the value of pagePathLevel3 ==> it will be the dates without all the rest of the URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

`https?:\/\/www\.essentialibiza\.com\/ibiza-club-tickets\/carl-cox[\w/_-]*`

Comment: You are right, @WiktorStribiżew, I have edit my answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

GA RE2 regex engine does not allow lookarounds (even lookaheads) in the pattern. You have defined one - `(?=(?:\/.*)?$)`.

If you need all links having `www.essentialibiza.com/ibiza-club-tickets/carl-cox/`, you can use a simple regex:

```
www\.essentialibiza\.com/ibiza-club-tickets/carl-cox/
```

If you want to precise the protocol:

```
https?://www\.essentialibiza\.com/ibiza-club-tickets/carl-cox(/|$)
```

The `?` will make `s` optional (1 or 0 occurrences) and `(/|$)` will allow matching the URL ending with `cox` (remove this group if you want to match URLs that only have `/` after `cox`).